# Logic for include layout

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I want to include the same layout in 6 different layouts. The layout has 2 buttons. I need the same actions for the buttons used for all layouts. How can I write the button logic once and use it in the 6 other layouts?

Comment: You can add logic into your layout using databinding or write a method  some where, write logic in it and call the method where ever required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom layout

```
public class ButtonLayout extends RelativeLayout {

private Context context;

public ButtonLayout (Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public ButtonLayout (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    init();
}

public ButtonLayout (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    this.context = context;
    init();
}

private void init (){
    inflate(context, R.layout.layout_buttons,this);
    Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1); //and handle button logic

}}
```

Then add the class in your layouts

```
<com.stackoverflow.custom butt.....
```